# Pandas: replace string with special characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (see after) in which I have two columns containing either a list of patients or an empty list (like that [''] ). I want to remove the empty list

What i have:

| Homozygous_list | heterozygous_list |
| --- | --- |
| [Patient1,Patient2] | [''] |
| [''] | [Patient1] |

What i want:

| Homozygous_list | heterozygous_list |
| --- | --- |
| [Patient1,Patient2] |  |
|  | [Patient1] |

I try several thing like :

```
variants["Homozygous_list"].replace("['']","", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
variants["Homozygous_list"].replace("\[''\]","", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
variants["Homozygous_list"] = variants["Homozygous_list"].replace("['']","", regex=True)
```

etc but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If both columns contain lists as the type, I don't have any problem with `['']` as an empty placeholder.  So I suggest not doing this operation at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have lists of strings, use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: '' if x==[''] else x)  # or pd.NA in place of ''
```

output:

```
       Homozygous_list  heterozygous_list
0  [Patient1, Patient2]                  
1                              [Patient1]
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Homozygous_list ': [['Patient1','Patient2'], ['']],
                   'heterozygous_list': [[''], ['Patient1']]})
```

Comment: Thank you ! 

I used apply instead of applymap to be specific to the column and it's work well :)

Solution :

`variants["Homozygous_list"] = variants["Homozygous_list"].apply(lambda x: '' if x==[''] else x)`

Comment: if you want to use a single column `variants["Homozygous_list"] = ['' if x==[''] else x for x in variants["Homozygous_list"]]` will be faster, if you want to apply on a subset of columns, slice before using `applymap`